# Adding graphics to Datatables cell if condition is met

Tags: python, flask, datatables

I'm pulling data from MySQL database with python/flask + flask-sqlalchemy and display it within html.

"**t.status**" can only has value of **0,1 or 2**.

This is how looks my html code:

```
<tbody>
    {% for t in tdata %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ t.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ t.objectid }}</td>
            <td>{{ t.status }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

which is working fine and displays all the status codes. Now I need to add tiny color icon for all 3 possible status codes. I tried following code, but it did'nt work:

```
<tbody>
    {% for t in tdata %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ t.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ t.objectid }}</td>
            <td>{{ if t.status == '0':
                       <img src="/static/images/red.png"> + t.status
                   elif t.status == '1':
                       <img src="/static/images/green.png"> + t.status
                   else:
                       <img src="/static/images/yellow.png"> + t.status }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: you can add css class.

Comment: Deepak Kumar, yes, I can change the <img> tag with css style, but the problem is that I need to add icon only when condition is met.

Comment: You are displaying images with using else if ladder. You can use the same thing for adding icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The {{ needs to be changed to {% and every line needs to be closed with %}. No ':' after elif.

```
<tbody>
{% for t in tdata %}
     <tr>
         <td>{{ t.id }}</td>
         <td>{{ t.objectid }}</td>
         <td>{% if t.status == 0 %}
                <span class="red"> ONE </span>
             {% elif t.status == 1 %}
                <span class="green"> TWO </span>
             {% elif t.status == 2 %}
                <span class="yellow"> THREE </span>
             {% endif %}
         </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add icon tag same as you added img tag.

```
<tbody>
    {% for t in tdata %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ t.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ t.objectid }}</td>
            <td> 
               <div>
                   {{ if t.status == '0':
                      <i class="fa fa-cloud"></i>
                       <img src="/static/images/red.png"> + t.status
                   elif t.status == '1':
                       <img src="/static/images/green.png"> + t.status
                   else:
                       <img src="/static/images/yellow.png" + t.status }}</td>
                </div>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Comment: I don't think we understand each other. The problem is with the if-else statement, not with displaying of some graphics.